# How to correctly add InstallShield-Projects under version control with VisualSVN in a VS-Solution

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2015, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, installshield-le

I'm currently switching from `TFS` to `VisualSVN` (client v5.1.3 / server v3.5.1).

In `TFS` the `InstallShieldLE`-Projects were also automatically under source control. (Marked with the TFS specific signs).
After `unbinding from TFS` and `adding the solution to VisualSVN`
by selecting `VisualSVN -> Add Solution to Subversion` in VS2015, they are not included by default anymore (missing traffic lights status icons for ISLE-Projects). I'm also missing  the "Add to subversion"-Option in the context menu  for this kind of projects in VS2015.

I know i'm able to add files manually via the `TortoiseSVN`-Context menu in windows explorer or CMD-line. But isn't there a `"built in way"` to do this? Because i dont want to take care by myself, if all files included to subversion correctly all the time...

[image: Solution-Explorer after SVN] ..........  [image: Windows Explorer after SVN]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the the following files manually, via the SVN-Contextmenu in
   Windows-Explorer did the trick. (Maybe some configuration changes at the 
VisualSVN-VS-Plugin will do this automatically)

After adding the following files manually from the InstallShield-Project-Folder:

- **[ProjectName].isl**
- **[ProjectName].isproj**

...the project seems to be correctly bound in VS:

[image: Afterwards in VisalStudio]